# From GET queries to WebSockets

Tags: php, websocket

My program is receiving an array of data by using GET requests. I need to rewrite it for using websockets.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET'){
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    if(!array_key_exists('method', $_GET) || !array_key_exists('login', $_GET)) die("");

    $params = strip($_GET);

    switch($params['method']){

        case 'method1': {
            // ...
        }
        case 'method2': {
            // ...
        }
        case 'method3': {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using PHP-WebSockets (https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-WebSockets)

Help  me, please.

Comment: Did you want someone here to rewrite this for you?

Comment: @JayBlanchard, No i didn't, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: OK - then try it. When you run into a problem you can come back here with your new code and we can help you.

Comment: And this isn't working... how?